# Relation does not exist for some users

Tags: postgresql, permissions

As a user with admin privileges in postgres, I can `psql database_name` and then invoke `\dt` to see a list of relations.  As the same (unix) user, I execute `psql -h localhost -U non-privileged-user table_name`, and `\dt` reports `NO relations found.`  The only `host` entries in `pg_hba.conf` are of the form `host    analytics             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5` (where 127.0.0.1 is the first entry).

Where are the relations?  Why are they not visible to the alternate user.  What schema tables should I look in to debug.  Also, note that `grant select on table_name to non-privileged-user` works just fine.

Comment: Nit-pick (not much relevant to the issue): when you `psql x` you login and connect to the **database** called `x`, not to a table named `x`.

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` is irrelevant to the question because it only controls _if_ a user is allowed to connect at all. But it does not control what the user can see once connected.

Answer (score 4):

What you see typically happens when the non-privileged user doesn't have *schema level* privileges.  In this case, they cannot list the objects inside the given schema - *with the command you tried*.  See the below example:

```
-- as a superuser, for example
CREATE DATABASE test;
\c test
CREATE TABLE public.blah (id integer);
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

CREATE USER u WITH PASSWORD 'u'; -- don't do this in production

-- connect as u
\c test u
\dt
No relations found.

-- but:
\dt public.*
       List of relations
 Schema │ Name │ Type  │ Owner  
────────┼──────┼───────┼────────
 public │ blah │ table │ dezso
```

See what the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS) says:

> **USAGE**
>
> For schemas, allows access to objects contained in the specified
>   schema (assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also
>   met). Essentially this allows the grantee to "look up" objects within
>   the schema. Without this permission, it is still possible to see the
>   object names, e.g. by querying the system tables. [...]

`\dt` does the latter, namely queries `pg_class` and `pg_namespace` to find matching objects.  Apparently, when the schema name is not specified, the system wants to hide objects from view.